# Error al generar un reporte en Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Alguien sabe porque pasa este error:

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Mensaje = An error occurred during local report processing.
  Origen = Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
  Seguimiento de la pila:
   en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   en Reports.ReportDefinitions.GetReportConsolidadoPagos(ConsolidadoPagosViewModel items) en D:\Projects2017\SkitProductos\Reports\ReportDefinitions.cs: línea 813
   en SKPMVC.Areas.Consultas.Controllers.ConsultaConsolidadosController.PopulateType(ConsultaControlViewModel app, String _search) en D:\Projects2017\SkitProductos\SKPMVC\Areas\Consultas\Controllers\ConsultaConsolidadosController.cs: línea 547
   en System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   en System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()

Excepción interna 1:
DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report '' is invalid.

Excepción interna 2:
ReportProcessingException: The report definition is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. This could be the result of publishing a report definition of a later version of Reporting Services, or that the report definition contains XML that is not well-formed or the XML is not valid based on the Report Definition schema. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.
```

Gracias

Comment: Desactiva el antivirus y el firewall y vuelve a ejecutar. A ver

Comment: agrega tu codigo para poder ver donde podria ser el problema

Comment: Aqui va: List<ReportParameter> lrp = new List<ReportParameter>();
            lrp.Add(new ReportParameter("FechaConsulta", items.Fecha.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")));
            FileDetail.LocalReport.SetParameters(lrp);

Comment: @JhonBohorquez prueba copiar Microsoft.ReportingServices.target en esta ruta C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\ReportingServices

Comment: @Raul Cacacho Microsoft.ReportingServices.target yo no tengo este archivo

Comment: @JhonBohorquez lo encuentras en C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\ReportingServices

Comment: @Raul Cacacho ya hice esto y no funciona

Comment: @JhonBohorquez es el mismo error o es otro, probaste ya agregar estos dll a tu carpeta bin del proyecto generado Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
, Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll

Comment: @Raul Cacacho ahora me aparece otro error